# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':compileReleaseAidl'

Tags: sdk, androidx

I've tried a bunch of answer and nothing has fixed this problem. Any assistance would be helpful.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':compileReleaseAidl'.

> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at '/Users/jake/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/assets_audio_player-2.0.13+1/android/local.properties'.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s

Exception: The plugin assets_audio_player could not be built due to the issue above.